# Is the ‘diffracting angle’ talking about the first minimum or first maximum?

Tags: terminology, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wave-optics

So when we talk about diffraction for single slits, we refer to the first minimum as the ‘diffracting angle’.

However, in other experiments with wave particle duality (for example electron scattering experiment) some textbooks refer to the diffracting angle as the first maximum (thinking of the diffracting screen as diffracting gratings since they are sheets of many atoms).

Overall, when textbooks and questions ask for the diffracting angle, should one use the first minimum formula (using slit width) or the first maximum formula (using slit separation)?

Comment: I deal with optics in my everyday life and I never heard anyone saying "diffraction angle" and meaning the first minimum.

Comment: @OfekGillon While I don't recall ever hearing that particular usage, it's clear what the OP has in mind. Single slit patterns have the opposite problem from diffraction gratings: the maxima are wide and smoothly varying while the minima are narrow and well defined, so for these patterns $\Delta \theta$s are generally measured to the minima.

Comment: Oh, now I got it. I really didn't understand that was the purpose of the question. Any how, it's still quite peculiar to me that this jargon exists. (I'm not familiar with it)